# Getting exception while save linq query result into ViewState

Tags: visual-web-part

Following is the code

```
SPList splist = web.Lists["MyList"];

var query = from SPListItem oItem in splist.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                            where !Convert.ToString(oItem["Status"]).Equals("Completed")
                            select oItem;

List<SPListItem> value = query.ToList<SPListItem>();
```

upto here working perfectly..

Now store value into viewstate getting following exception

```
ViewState.Add("Key", value);
```

**Exception**

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' in Assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Thanks

Comment: The result of this query is SPListItems which are not serializable and cannot be added to the ViewState. This query may return a large amount of items and it is not recommended to save them in ViewState. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: i want get same linq query result during button click event
bcz i don't trip to database(SPList) again.

Comment: @hitz Do the query again on button click instead of saving in ViewState!

Comment: You really should be running a CAML query. Using linq fetches all the items in the list before filtering them. If you have thousands of items, this will kill the server